# Unable to get an accurate threshold of an image with a bright spot

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to detect a huge bright blob in an image. The way I'm doing it is, I'm first converting it to `COLOR_BGR2HLS_FULL`, taking the green channel and applying GuassianBlur to it like so and then I'm using `THRESH_OTSU` to obtain the thresholded image and then drawing the contour:

```
self.result = cv2.cvtColor(self.result_array_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS_FULL)
self.result = self.result[:,:,1] 
self.result = cv2.GaussianBlur(self.result,(25,25), 0)
```

Here's what the obtained image looks like:

[image]

And here's what the desired image should look like:

[image]

Also, my way of going about this isn't consistent with all the images of similar type. Is there a better way you could suggest?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I haven't use any other inpainting techniques to remove the vessels.
Dilate is the maximum value inside some area and Erode is the minimum value. I used Dilate and Erode radius 32 and HighPass radius 128.

The code is in C# :

```
    public byte[] Dilate(byte[] image, int width, int height, int radius)
{
    byte[] temp = new byte[image.Length];
    byte[] result = new byte[image.Length];

    //Dilate by X
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            byte v = 0;
            for (int i = x - radius; i <= x + radius; i++)
                if (i >= 0 && i < width)
                    v = Math.Max(v, image[i + y * width]);
            temp[x + y * width] = v;
        }

    //Dilate by Y
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            byte v = 0;
            for (int i = y - radius; i <= y + radius; y++)
                if (i >= 0 && i < height)
                    v = Math.Max(v, temp[x + i * width]);
            result[x + y * width] = v;
        }

    return result;
}

public byte[] Erode(byte[] image, int width, int height, int radius)
{
    byte[] temp = new byte[image.Length];
    byte[] result = new byte[image.Length];

    //Dilate by X
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            byte v = 255;
            for (int i = x - radius; i <= x + radius; i++)
                if (i >= 0 && i < width)
                    v = Math.Min(v, image[i + y * width]);
            temp[x + y * width] = v;
        }

    //Dilate by Y
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            byte v = 255;
            for (int i = y - radius; i <= y + radius; y++)
                if (i >= 0 && i < height)
                    v = Math.Min(v, temp[x + i * width]);
            result[x + y * width] = v;
        }

    return result;
}

public byte[] HighPass(byte[] image, int width, int height, float radius)
{
    byte[] smooth = GaussSmooth(image, width, height, (byte)radius);
    byte[] result = new byte[image.Length];

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            result[x + y * width] = (byte)(128 + image[x + y * width] - smooth[x + y * width]);
        }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got to achieve this result:

Initial image (I did not have the original one so I removed the green line from yours):

[image]

Use GREEN channel for processing:

[image]

Then use Dilate and Erode filter with square window with radius 32 to remove vessels:

After Dilate
[image]

After Erode
[image]

The Lighting Suppression filter (or High-Pass filter - division by Gauss smooth of the image) to make image more plain:

[image]

And finally a threshold

[image]

[image]

You can also smooth the final mask

[image]

And use threshold again to obtain more smooth result:

[image]

Comment: That's excellent. Do you mind including the code? I'm most curious about the dilate and erode part, and also the  Lighting Suppression filter . Thank you.

Comment: What was the kernel size of dilation. Please provide a little more info if you can. Did you use inpainting to remove the vessels?